# Monodroid Dialog transparent background

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-dialog

I am trying to set my dialog background transparent in Xamarin android but I can't manage to achieve properly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFYZs.jpg

There is a blue line on top of dialog even though I made background transparent. How can I make my background fully transparent. Thank you.

**Main Activity;**

```
[Activity(Label = "LoadingExample2", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private Dialog builder;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            builder = new Dialog(this);
            var view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Loading,null);
            builder.SetContentView(view);
            builder.Window.SetBackgroundDrawableResource(global::Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);

            button.Click += delegate
            {
                builder.Show();
            };
        }
    }
```

**Loading.axml;**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Loading"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_below="@id/progressBar1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to hide the bar itself :

```
int divierId = builder.Window.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
builder.Window.FindViewById(divierId)
 .SetBackgroundColor(Resources.GetColor(global::Android.Resource.Color.Transparent));
```

Comment: Thank you this works like a charm. If you can explain what those lines of code doing, I would be much more grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Good point, so android is not providing a public static pointer to the title divider View of a dialog. Otherwise it would have be accessible through `Android.Resource.Id.TitleDivider` that could be have been passed to the `FindViewById`. So we're getting a reference to it dynamically using `GetIdentifier`. And once we've found the divider view, we're applying a transparent color, so technically it's still there, but invisible.

Comment: Thank you for explanation and for your help. I hope other people who may get same problem would get benefit from this solution.

Comment: How can I set the CustomDialogfragment background to transparent?